# postfix, relay local domain

Tags: linux, postfix

I have virtualmin and settings on virtualhost: mailname and hosts mydomain.com

I have all my emails accounts on gmail e.g. support@mydomain.com

However when sending emails in Joomla (PHP Mail setting) I have in mail.log

```
 8BB689FE64: to=<support@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.03/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "support")
```

It treats mydomain.com as local, this domain is on gmail.

When sending to other than mydomain.com it send fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) Have a look in /etc/postfix for any mention of mydomain.com

2) Add the following line to /etc/postfix/transport

> mydomain.com smtp:SERVER

where SERVER is the correct mail server (MX record) for your domain at gmail.com. You could try putting gmail.com, but I'm not sure. Have a look for the right answer using "host mydomain.com" or dig.

Then run:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

Restart postfix and Bob's your uncle. Hopefully...

Comment: I had changed mydomain.com in main.cf but did not help as domain A points to my server

Comment: Did the transport stuff not help?

Comment: nope still relay=local instead to google apps

Comment: OP fixed the issue: "I fixed the issue by not setting the mydestination param in main.cf."

Comment: don't specified the domain mydestination or virtual_mailbox_domains, because your domain is in an external mail server